rust tokio::sync::mpsc::channel is_empty() returning false when len() returns 0
I have a tokio::sync::mpsc::channel open and the receiver's is_empty() method is returning false when len() method is returning 0.
This only happens after 32 loops. Weird.
Anyone have ideas on why this might be happening?

Digging into the source, beyond some trivial layers it appears to come down to these methods in which is_empty() is not written purely in terms of len(), but I do not know enough about the structure to know when this behavior may occur.

This is a bug, I have opened an issue on the tokio project.
Like I said there, channels internally use blocks of 32 values, so this may explain why this happens every 32 sends.
Edit: a correction has already been posted
